# How can I add a white space between image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I write a code to loop for creating multiple image on UIImageView inside scrollview. i did something like this:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(38, 9, 90, 280)];
int numberOfImages = 9;
CGFloat currentY = 0.5f;

for (int i=1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img0%d.jpg",i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 15, 87, imageView.frame.size.height - 20);

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = currentY;
    imageView.frame = rect;

    currentY += imageView.frame.size.height;
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(87,currentY);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Now, i need to add a space between each image, how can i do that?

Comment: just try to change your y coordinate as your need..as simple as that..

Comment: Maybe apply some logic? Horribile dictu, elementary geometry?

Comment: Also, this is not related to Xcode in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a bit more to `currentY`?

```
currentY += imageView.frame.size.height + 12.0f;
```